# Lambda with no parameter is returning function and not result of function

Tags: kotlin

I have this lambda that I would like to return the result of String via `CommonIdFacade.commonId`, but what is actually returned is the function. `MDC.get` returns a string

```
typealias CommonIdFactory =  () -> String
class CommonIdFacade {
    companion object {
        var commonId: CommonIdFactory =  { MDC.get("someKey") }
            internal set
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the curly brackets: `var commonId: CommonIdFactory =  MDC.get("someKey")`

Comment: When I do that my IDE says " 
Type mismatch.
Required:
CommonIdFactory /* = () → String */
Found:
String!" I could change the type Alias to just be a string but I would like for it to be a lambda

Comment: And you miss closing double quotes: _MDC.get("someKey)_

Comment: well you have to decide what you want. `{ xxx }` is defining a function. This function is stored in `commonId`. If you call this function via `CommonIdFacade().commonId()` it will return a String, which is exactly what you describe with `() -> String`. If you want `commonId` to just return a String, you have to say so when defining the typealias: `typealias CommonIdFactory =  String`. It's either one or the other. "String" or "function that returns a String"

Comment: @hello2244 what exactly do you want to set when you set it? A value or a different factory?

Answer (score 6):

In your code, the type alias says that `CommonIdFactory` is a *function that returns a string*, not just a string:

```kotlin
typealias CommonIdFactory =  () -> String
```

So if you declare `commonId` as a `CommonIdFactory`, it will itself be a function that needs to be invoked to get the string.

There are several options depending on how you want to access the variable and set it.

### Option 1: String property - get and set as a string

If you want `commonId` to be a string when you access it, it shouldn't be of type `CommonIdFactory`, but of type `String` instead.

```kotlin
class CommonIdFacade {
    companion object {
        var commonId: String = MDC.get("someKey")
            internal set
    }
}

// get value directly
val id = CommonIdFacade.commonId
// set a new value
CommonIdFacade.commonId = "some value"
```

This would initialize `commonId` immediately to the value of `MDC.get("someKey")`, and it will not change unless you set it to a different value. Setting a value will not affect the underlying `MDC` here, because `MDC` is only used for the initialization of `commonId`, then `commonId` has its own independent value that can be changed at will.

### Option 2: Computed string property - recompute the value each time

If what you want is that each *access* to `commonId` gets a fresh value from `MDC`, you should write it in a getter:

```kotlin
class CommonIdFacade {
    companion object {
        var commonId: String
            get() = MDC.get("someKey")
            internal set(value) {
                MDC.set("someKey", value)
            }
}

// get value directly
val id = CommonIdFacade.commonId
// set a new value
CommonIdFacade.commonId = "some value"
```

In this case you should likely implement the setter in a way that modifies MDC, which may or may not be your intention.

### Option 3: Get it as function, set as function

Now, if you *do* want `commonId` to be a function, you can declare it as you did, but then you need to access it as a function:

```kotlin
typealias CommonIdFactory =  () -> String
class CommonIdFacade {
    companion object {
        var commonId: CommonIdFactory =  { MDC.get("someKey") }
            internal set
    }
}

// get value by invoking the function
val id = CommonIdFacade.commonId()
// set a different factory
CommonIdFacade.commonId = { SomewhereElse.getValue() }
```

### Option 4: Get it as string, but set new factories

Last but not least, maybe you want to set different factory functions but access it as a string property nonetheless:

```kotlin
typealias CommonIdFactory =  () -> String
class CommonIdFacade {
    companion object {
        internal var commonIdFactory: CommonIdFactory = { MDC.get("someKey") }

        val commonId: String
            get() = commonIdFactory.invoke()
    }
}

// get the value directly
val id = CommonIdFacade.commonId
// set a different factory
CommonIdFacade.commonIdFactory = { SomewhereElse.getValue() }
```

In this case you can set new factory functions via a different property, and access the result of the factory via the `commonId` property.

---

Side note: if there is no instance-level state in `CommonIdFacade`, you can declare it as an `object` itself instead of `class`, so you don't have to shove everything into its `companion object`:

```kotlin
object CommonIdFacade {
    internal var commonIdFactory: CommonIdFactory = { MDC.get("someKey") }

    val commonId: String
        get() = commonIdFactory.invoke()
}
```

Side note 2: mutable globals have a tendency to break things. Do you really need this?

Comment: @hello224 If this answer was helpful for you/correct, please mark it so by clicking the checkmark below its upvote count.